# Convert from List<String> to List<Character> Java

Tags: string, list, collections, java-8, character

AFAIK, Some possible conversions are

```
List<String> stringList = integerList.stream().map(Object::toString)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and

```
List<Integer> integerList = stringList.stream()
        .map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

is there any conversions like the above to convert from list of string to list of character??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure:

```
List<Character> result = 
    stringList.stream()
              .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
              .mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char) i)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or simply

```
List<Character> result = 
    stringList.stream()
              .flatMapToInt(String::chars)
              .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```